# How to toggle MYSQL tinyint value in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to toggle MYSQL "is_active" value from course table on click of button.

The model function is as follows:

```
function statusCourse($id){
    $data = array(
        'is_active' => '!is_active'
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('course', $data);
}
```

The is_active column from course table is tinyint.

Comment: Pretty Unclear what you want to achieve over here

Comment: @Uchiha What is unclear?

Comment: default value 0 in table?

Comment: to toggle between 1 and 0 usually you would do `1 - field_value` ~ so perhaps `1-is_active`?

Comment: You will probably have to switch to regular sql instead of using an ORM if you want to do it in 1 query.

Comment: You just want to toogle only in sql just in one statement ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do same functionality by below way:-

```
// If is_active=1 then it become 0. If 0 then become 1.
$sql = "UPDATE course SET is_active = IF(is_active=1, 0, 1)";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just update the column? This will UPDATE a column:

```
function statusCourse($id)
{
    $data = array(
          'is_active' => 0 //0 for false, 1 for true 
           );
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->update('course'); //sets $id to 0, this COULD mean inactive. Your decision
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late but i have simple and very good short method:

```
function changeStatus($id){
   $sql = "UPDATE course SET is_active = 1-is_active where id = ".$id;
   $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

this is going to toggle the value from 1 to 0 OR 0 to 1;

Answer (score -2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuario`;
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_usuario` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cargo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo_nacional` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo_internacional` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nav_nacional` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `direccion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```